# Do I need to recompile PHP extensions ever time I upgrade to a newer version of PHP?

Tags: php, php-extension

I'm using 3rd party extensions that requires compilation to generate the `.so` file:

```
/usr/bin/phpize

./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --disable-memcached-sasl

make

make install
```

My question is, if I update PHP from 7.1.0 to 7.1.1, do I need to manually recompile all the `.so` extensions?

Or there's no need to recompile if I'm staying within the 7.1.x branch?

Comment: it's depends on the extension itself, for example, if you are using phthreads on php5 -which is mean that you are probably using pthreads2- and upgraded from php5 to php7 , you will have to upgrade pthread to the latest major version, pthread3 , and so on;

Comment: If I'm only upgrading with the 7.1.x version branches, can I skip the recompilation for extensions?  I have several manually compiled extensions, it's a lot of manual work if I need to do it one by one whenever I do a minor PHP version update.

Comment: actually I don't know a good/easy way to track the outdated installed extension in php, and i'm afraid -if there are not- that you willhave to do it manually, however, its worse to search for it;